# Can we set the environment variable of AWS python lambda on invocation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I have a python AWS lambda that hits a REST endpoint, if the service/endpoint is down or unreachable I want to send a notification to a teams/slack channel.

I don't want to keep sending this notification for every message while the service is down. I would like to send one message the first time it is down and then send another when it is back up.

I was thinking of having an environment variable SERVICE_UP = true. If we get an error saying service is down we notify the channel and set SERVICE_UP = false, when it changes again we send a notification saying service back up and set SERVICE_UP = true.

Pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve or else open to other suggestions, not sure i DynamoDB table might be overkill for what i am trying to achieve?

```
if (SERVICE_UP == true):
   if (failed_call):
     send_notification()
     SERVICE_UP = false;

if (SERVICE_UP == false):
   if (successful_call):
     send_notification()
     SERVICE_UP = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you can't set the environment variables during invocation, as they are part of lambda's configuration. Thus you can use [update-function-configuration](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html) API call to set their values in **unpublished function** only. If the function is published (i.e. it has a version) then the environment variables are immutable.

As a workaround you can store variable `SERVICE_UP` externally, e.g. in [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to persist its value between invocations.

The other workaround, if your function is unpublished, would be to use AWS SDK in the function to call `update-function-configuration` so that the function updates its own environment variables.

For short term storage of the `SERVICE_UP` value, you could use [AWS Lambda execution context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) which persists between function executions for some time. But its not permanent.

Comment: Thanks this is good information, if it has a version not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS param store and keep this flag there.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html